# How to connect to my own server via mysql_connect php function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to analyze queries sending to MySQL server.
Also program (which sending queries) code should be the same
So, here is function to connect to MySQL server:

```
if (mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '12345')) {
        mysql_select_db('db');
    } else {
        print "connection failed....";
    }
```

I created my own severs with ip 127.0.0.3 and listened port 3303.
So, I rewrite this function like this:

```
if (mysql_connect('127.0.0.3:3303', 'root', '12345')) {
            mysql_select_db('db');
        } else {
            print "connection failed....";
        }
```

When I try to connect my server see a connection, but doesn't receive any data, such as login ('root') and password. So, I can't to connect to MySQL from my server-program

What can be the best solution?
Thanks

Comment: try local_host as the instead of the IP address

Comment: @Michael: it's `localhost`. And I've just noticed it isn't: 127.0.0.3

Comment: If you're thinking of using this in a web application, don't. Use PDO http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: @vladimar: You see a connection where? And how exactly is it not working? mysql_connect() either connects or not, and if it doesn't it will return FALSE and mysql_error() will possibly tell you why.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Here is mysql_error(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Comment: @Calum thanks, I'm going to look at this

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario You are correct, I was typing faster than my brain could autocorrect. +1 for error correction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, the standard mysql port is 3306. I would check the config file on 127.0.0.3 to make sure that is the port that is set and that there is no firewall blocking that port.

As a guess, I would make sure you have

```
# skip-networking
```

in the config file. On some installations, `skip-networking` is **enabled** by default and the sever won't listen for connections from other computers.

Also, it's possible the server will not forward any packets to 127.0.0.x, as that is reserved for localhost. To determine that, make sure basic networking is working between the two computers (ping, traceroute).

Comment: I think mysql_connect() should send some data, but I can't read it.
It's my problem

Comment: @vladimar You should back up and test the basic networking before blaming mysql_connect().

Answer (score 0):

Spitting out a fixed "connection failed" error message is utterly useless for debugging purposes. Try this instead:

```
if (mysql_connect('127.0.0.3:3303', 'root', '12345')) {
    ...
} else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Have MySQL tell you EXACTLY what the problem is, instead of just saying there's a problem and flailing around in the dark.